# How to change a JSON value in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a `jsObject` that looks like this `{"Name": "Milan", "Surname": "Smolik"}` hardcoded somewhere else in app and parsed with [this](https://github.com/matteosb/kotlin-json-builder) library. When I `println(fullName)`, I get `{"name": "Milan", "surname": "Smolik"}`.

Now, I would like to modify `Name` to `Martin`. How do I do that?

In JavaScript I would either `fullName.name = 'Martin'` or `newName = {...fullName, name: 'Martin'}`. 
Can I do that in Kotlin? Is there some library that would support modifying JSONs / JSON spread operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't do it on the fly, you must map `JSON` into a `data class` and change any field you want in it and convert it to `JSON` again.

First create a data class:

```
data class YourModel(
  val Name: String,
  val Surname: String
)
```

Use [`GSON`](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.google.code.gson%20AND%20a:gson) to convert `JSON` to `object` like as below:

```
var yourModel = gson.fromJson(yourJsonString, YourModel::class.java)
```

and then change any field you want like as below:

```
yourModel.Name = "Martin"
```

finally you can convert it to `JSON` string again:

```
var jsonString = gson.toJson(yourModel)
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin JS objects are [dynamic](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/dynamic-type.html), i.e. it is allowed to call any property or function with any parameters on a dynamic variable. So, just do `obj.Name = "Martin"` and it should work:

```
fun main() {
    val obj = js("{'Name': 'Milan', 'Surname': 'Smolik'}")

    obj.Name = "Martin"

    println(JSON.stringify(obj))
}
```

A [link](https://pl.kotl.in/I5NdkvBCe) to playground.

Comment: Thanks! But I am recieving `Unresolved reference: js`. Are `js` and `JSON` in some package?

Comment: `The dynamic type is not supported in code targeting the JVM`